# Is there a way to search for questions/answers I've commented on?

Tags: feature-request, comments

If someone replies to one of my comments using the @Martha syntax, SE kindly lets me know about it. If someone doesn't use that syntax, or replies to someone else, I'm not notified, so the only way I will read the response is if I happen to come back to the same question on my own.

There are also cases where I leave comments suggesting an improvement or clarification. If the author makes the suggested changes but doesn't leave a reply-comment of his own, again, I have to come back to the question on my own.

Is there a way to list questions or answers I have commented on? I know the whole commenting interface is a bit of an afterthought/stepchild, but I still think this would be a useful function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We now have a [data dump](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/queries) for English Language and Usage, and you can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/q/16440/my-latest-comments) (or something similar) to get what you want:

```
select top 500
PostId as [Post Link],
CreationDate,
[Text],
Score
from Comments c  
where UserId = ##UserId##
order by CreationDate DESC
```

For those unfamiliar with Data Explorer: the above query requires that you specify the ID of the user for which you wish to run it. To find out your (or somebody else's) ID on a particular site, visit your (or that user's) user profile on that site and have a look at the browser address bar. The URL there will be of the form `http://sitename.stackexchange.com/users/NUMBER/username`. The `NUMBER` is the ID you're looking for.

Contrary to my speculation in an earlier comment, the dumps are still updated only once a month. (To my defense, they *did* get updated several times in the first week of December.) So, in order to keep track of your most recent comments, you'll have to rely on the "Activity" tab in your user profile, as Mitch has suggested. And if there's a gap between what's covered by the tab and what's covered by the dump, I guess you'll just have to wait for the next dump.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, except I'm not sure I can interpret the blog post to mean that they're expanding the data dumps to include all the newer SE sites. I'll keep my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to your profile by clicking your name at the top of any SE page, then go to the "Activity" tab, it will list your activities in reverse chronological order, including comments. The format of the URL is

```
http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/users/<user-number-here>?tab=activity
```

**UPDATE:** Forgot that, since I'm new here, I haven't seen what happens when the activity page has aged. Apparently for older comments this approach does not work.

Comment: That only shows activity from the last *n* days (haven't figured out what *n* is, but it's not terribly long). If there's a way to look at older activity, I haven't found it.

Comment: @Martha: I was unaware of that. Thanks for the info. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: It seems that now, the activity tab is [paginated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55291/add-paging-for-user-activity-section). Looks like it's time for another update. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say using Google [this way](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com+%22%40Martha%22) ought to work.

Comment: It doesn't, actually, or not reliably.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, putting the question that you want to follow as favourite would let you know whenever a new comment is made, wherever it was made.