# Is there any way I could follow a question asked by someone else?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Over my brief time spent here on EL&U, I have seen some questions posted by other users which I would like to know the answer to/follow. One option is I could up-vote them and then later, I check them in up-voted questions section in the activity tab but this would only work till the day the number of questions eventually accumulate so much that finding that particular question would become some task in itself. Same thing holds true if I mark them as a favorite. Is there any other-more easier and a robust way to do this?

While I was searching for this question if it already exists, I came across this question [Is there a way to search for questions/answers I've commented on?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/480/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-questions-answers-ive-commented-on) and the accepted answer talks about data-dump and a query search and it has a problem with regular updates and it made me wonder if there's a similar method to keep track of the questions of my interest. If not, it would be helpful to make a separate 'follow' tab beside every question so as to get regular notifications.

Answer (score 5):

You can "favourite" a **question**, tick the grey star underneath the arrows

[image]

this becomes a "gold" star

[image]

On your profile page click on *favorites*

[image]

The page will show a list of questions you have starred.

Answer (score 3):

Not within the SE interface. The official position seems to be that [favoriting = following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13546/please-allow-me-to-follow-questions) (I think this conflation is a problem, but that's just my opinion) or people will tell you to use other resources like RSS feeds. While it's tough to look through them once you get a lot of favorites, the tab for them does list the most recently active ones first, and it highlights any that have been changed since you last viewed the tab.

Comment: No -> Not within the SE interface: +1 for that alone without reading any further.
By the way, how do we use RSS feed button? I see an orange 'question feed' button at the bottom and when I click, I get a new tab where some text is written on it. What do I do with that?

Comment: @JonyAgarwal: you need [RSS reader software](http://www.whatisrss.com). I've never used it, so I don't have any particular recommendations.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I will dig more into it then.